# Random number of successes in a random number of trials

Tags: probability

Consider a series of Bernoullian trials with constant probability $p$ of success.Let $n$ and $x$ be two independent and uniform variables chosen respectively from the sets $\{1,2,..N\}$ and $\{0,1,2..N\}$.How can we find an expression for $x$ successes in $n$ trials  where $n$ and $x$ are chosen as above? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @leonbloy thanks a lot for the edit

Answer (score 0):

Let $y$ be the number of successes; then, conditioned to $n$, it's a binomial.

$$P(y \mid n) = {n \choose y} p^y (1-p)^{n-y} \, [0\le y\le n]$$

Then $P(y) = \sum_n P(y , n)  = \sum_{n=1}^N P(y \mid n) P(n) = \sum_{n=1}^N P(y \mid n) \frac{1}{N} $

We want $P(y=x) = \sum_{t=0}^N P(Y=t) P(X=t)=\sum_{y=0}^N P(y) \frac{1}{N+1}$

Can you go on from here?